# Interact with collection in Javascript

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm beginning Meteor, and discovering mongodb along the way.

I have a collection, called Chansons.

```
export const Chansons = new Mongo.Collection('chansons');
```

And the user can add elements to the collection, using a button.

```
Template.search.events({
  'click #Ajouter' : function(){
    const vidURL = document.getElementById("URL").value;
    Chansons.insert({
      URL : vidURL
    });
```

How could I, in the code, get an array with all the URLs from the elements in the collection? The same result as if I were doing

```
db.chansons.find({},{URL:1,_id:0})
```

in the terminal. I'm sure this is fairly basic, but I'm a bit lost in all the documentation online.

Comment: You need to publish the relevant on the server, subscribe to it, and query it from the client side. Read about Meteor pub/sub.

Comment: Did you try `Chansons.find({},{URL:1,_id:0})`?

Comment: @MasterAM given that OP inserts on client side and says is beginning with Meteor, it is very likely they still have `insecure` and `autopublish` packages on.

Comment: I do indeed have them on. I'll read the doc and try to figure it out.

Comment: Before I answer I need to know if you want an array of documents that only contain the URL field, or do you want an array containing all the URL fields from all the documents? `[{ URL: 'http://..' }, { URL: 'http://' }]` or `[ 'http://..', 'http://...' ]`?

Comment: Hey @KellyCopley sorry for the late answer I was on holidays. I would rather have an array containing all the URL fields `[ 'http://..', 'http://...' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the `cursor.map` method.

```
const URLs = Chansons.find({},{ fields: { URL: 1, _id: 0 } }).map((chanson) => chanson.URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a similar command in the browser console:

```
Chansons.find({},{fields: {URL:1,_id:0}})
```

Or you can return it within a helper method:

```
Template.search.helpers({
  'data'() { return Chansons.find({},{fields: {URL:1,_id:0}}) }
})
```

and then use it in your Blaze template

```
<ul>
   {{#each d in data}}
     <li> {{d.URL}} </li>
   {{/each}}
</ul>
```